# Do all serial ports start with COM?

Tags: windows, serial-port

Pretty straight forward question. Do all COM ports (on Windows) start with COM (e.g. COM1, COM2, etc.)?

Looking at tools like `com0com`, I see ports named CNCA1 and CNCB2.

Could I have a COM port named anything (like a pipe)?

Comment: Clearly you already know the answer.  It is up to the device driver to register device names in the `\DosDevices` namespace.  Anything goes.  Underlying call is IoCreateSymbolicLink().

Comment: How would I already know the answer then? I wasn't sure if CNC* and COM* were reserved namespaces. You should add your response as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: I can't tell what problem you are trying to solve so don't know how to post the most appropriate answer.  Is it just curiosity?

Comment: Yes, curiosity. Could not find anything as definitive as your answer online. Thanks.